# Git, two commits that have not merged together properly

Tags: git

We have two git commits like below, the two have not merged in together for some reason (the one at the top does not contain the changes from the one at the bottom).

[image: git unmerged]

(I am not sure why my image is not working...it looks like this)

```
* 5d0a88b (parent is 770c522)
|
* \  770c522 (missing files from a135e1a))  (parent is 8a25483)
   |
* -|  a135e1a   (parent is 8a25483)
   |
   * 8a25483 (this is the parent of both commits above)
   |
   *  
   |
   *
```

I have tried merging a135e1a into my current working copy using

```
git merge a135e1a
```

but it tells me that the merge has been successful.

Comment: Tell us how you’re trying to merge. Also if possible, include the actual sha1 values (you can shorten them), so we can refer to them correctly.

Comment: yep, updated - I also found out that both commits have the same parent

Comment: What does your working copy point to when you attempt to merge?

Comment: Have you reverted this merge previously? If you revert a merge commit and then try merging the branch again, the changes won't show up.

Comment: I have not reverted the merge (at least to my knowledge)

Comment: @codelark, I have updated the question - my current commit points to 770c522, so now a135e1a is just sitting there unmerged

Comment: So, just to be clear, after the git tells you that the merge is "successful", the changes in `a135e1a` is not in your current HEAD and there is no new `merge commit` show up?

Comment: Try merge with options `--no-ff` to force a non-fastforward commit **OR** try to rebase by using `git rebase a135e`

Comment: Can you include the output of `git log --decorate --oneline --graph`?

Comment: The easiest way to include a single commit is to use `cherry-pick`.  Try `git cherry-pick a135e1a`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, any one of those comments may have worked but I had to fix it earlier than they came in.  In the end I checked out the two commits into separate local branches and then merged them (which worked).  I then copied the generated code over the top of my workspace and did a commit.

I realise that this was not the best solution but it was the only way I could get it working at the time.